# How can I convert multiple XML files in CSV automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, xml

I have about one hundred of XML file (with the same structure) and I want to import them in SAS. Unfortunately in doing that I have some issues relatated to the MAP file of the XML files (I have not the MAP file for these files). So I though to convert these files in CSV through Excel. But if I use this path, I need something that is able to convert massively all my XML files in CSV, because clearly I can't convert by hands every file individually.

Anyone knows how can I solve?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add an example input file?

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your problem?

Comment: [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=88678725792875981823)

Comment: I've added in the comment a link to an example of my XML files

Comment: the file you linked is an XLSX (Excel) file, not an XML file. Do you want to convert XML --> CSV or XLSX --> CSV ?

Comment: @Sir Adelaide If you open the tab "developer" in excel, you can see the XML source of the file I've attached. I need to convert XML files like that in CSV or XLSX

Comment: @GiacomoRosaspina I do not have excel, than I cannot open the tab "developer".
If you need help please share an example XML file.

Comment: @Sir Adelaide http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=99433598766384479322

Comment: @GiacomoRosaspina the XML has a complex structure. What do you want to have in CSV output? What's the CSV schema? https://i.imgur.com/BVrMJ9R.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve my issue with this VBA script:

```
Public Sub ConvertXmlToXlsx()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

xmlFolder = "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\"
convFolder = "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\"


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(xmlFolder)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If UCase(Right(objFile.Name, Len(XML))) = UCase(XML) Then
        NewFileName = convFolder & objFile.Name & ".xlsx"

        Workbooks.OpenXML (objFolder & "\" & objFile.Name), LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileName

        ActiveWorkbook.Close

    End If
Next objFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be familiar with SAS, or you'll have to be soon, I'd use R to read out the Excel files and then write them again as CSV.

The code below allows you to set the working directory, read the contents onto a list and iterate through the list to conver the files in a few lines.

```
library(readxl)
setwd("The directory containing your files")
list <- list.files()
for(i in 1:length(list)) {
  Intermediate <- read_excel(list[i])
  write.csv(Intermediate, paste0(list[i],".csv"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the following code you can use any XSLT-2.0 processor to convert your XML to a CSV file.

The XML file should have a structure like this:

```
<AnyRoot>
  <AnyEntry>
    <Value1></Value1>
    <Value2></Value2>
    <Value3></Value3>
    ...
  </AnyEntry>
  <AnyEntry>
    <Value1></Value1>
    ...
  </AnyEntry>
  ...
</AnyRoot>
```

For this example I use the following XML file:

```
<root>
    <Entry>
      <CSVValue1>A</CSVValue1>
      <CSVValue2>"B"</CSVValue2>
      <CSVValue3>C,D</CSVValue3>
      <CSVValue4>"E","F"</CSVValue4>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <CSVValue1>G H</CSVValue1>
      <CSVValue2>""</CSVValue2>
      <CSVValue3></CSVValue3>
      <CSVValue4 />
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <CSVValue1>1996</CSVValue1>
      <CSVValue2>Jeep</CSVValue2>
      <CSVValue3>Grand Cherokee</CSVValue3>            
      <CSVValue4>MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded</CSVValue4>
      <CSVValue5>4999.00</CSVValue5>            
    </Entry>
</root>
```

And this is the XSLT-2.0 stylesheet you can use to transform all of your XML files to CSV files. As far as I have tested it, it works for [all cases described in the specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). But, to be honest, I cannot guarantee that. You have to test it and give some feedback here.

However, here is the XSLT-2.0 code that converts XML to CSV:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<!-- ================================================================= -->
<!-- XML to CSV Version 1.0 by zx485 on 30-01-2019@01:58               -->
<!-- Run it with java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:XML2CSV.xslt input.xml    -->
<!-- ================================================================= -->
    <xsl:variable name="csvItems">
      <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[1]/*">
        <Item name="{local-name()}" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:value-of select="$csvItems/Item/@name" separator="," />
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>      

    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".='&quot;&quot;'">
          <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;&quot;'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(.,',') or contains(.,'&#xa;')">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',.,'&quot;')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(.,'&quot;')">
          <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'&quot;','&quot;&quot;')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(.,',') and contains(.,'&quot;')">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',replace(.,'&quot;','&quot;&quot;'),'&quot;')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output of this is:**

```
CSVValue1,CSVValue2,CSVValue3,CSVValue4
A,""B"","C,D",""E","F""
G H,"",,
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4999.00
```

If you put this transformation in a loop of a script, you can transform many XML files at once.

Comment: Where I have to put your XSLT-2.0 code that converts XML to CSV?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. You copy the code to an `.xslt` file like `XML2CSV.xslt` and then apply it to all the XML files via a bash script calling an XSLT processor or something like that. For example with the command `for f in *.xml; do java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:XML2CSV.xslt "$f"; done`. You only have to redirect the output to the files you want.